# Objective-C Syntactical Question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax, nsstring

Just doing some research on searching for a character or word within a NSString and I came across this code snippet (which works like a charm):

```
return [sourceString rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound;
```

Am I right in thinking that the above code is functionally identical to:

```
NSRange range = [sourceString rangeOfString:searchString];
if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    return NSNotFound;
else
    return range.location;
```

Obviously the first snippet is much cleaner but I'm not clear on the `!= NSNotFound` part. Could someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `!=` operator evaluates to a boolean, so it's equivalent to:

```
NSRange range = [sourceString rangeOfString:searchString];
if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    return NO;
else
    return YES;
```

Which is the same as:

```
NSRange range = [sourceString rangeOfString:searchString];
BOOL didNotFind = (range.location == NSNotFound);
return !didNotFind;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually no, it's equivalent to:

```
NSRange range = [sourceString rangeOfString:searchString];
if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    return NO;
else
    return YES;
```

Which can be written shorter as:

```
NSRange range = [sourceString rangeOfString:searchString];
BOOL result = range.location != NSNotFound;
return result;
```

Comment: You have to either compare using `!=` or return `!result` in the second version.

Comment: @georg Obviously. :) Corrected.